# systemctl --type=service and systemctl list-unit-files do not show all services

Tags: debian, services, manjaro, systemctl, sysctl

I have wireguard installed on a Manjaro host, and Debian Server host

The following commands show **wireguard** in the results on Manjaro, but nothing on the Debian server, yet the **wireguard** is definitely running on the debian server.

```
systemctl --type=service
systemctl --type=service --all
systemctl list-unit-files
```

Why does debian server not show any footprint of **wireguard**? and possibly other *services* that I am unable to also see?

**EDIT :**
systemctl list-unit-files

**wg-quick.target** shows up in debian server

but nothing still for

```
systemctl -at service
```

Comment: Are you searching for the string `wireguard` specifically? The service appears to be templated as `wg-quick@.service` and instantiated as something like `wg-quick@wg0.service` when interface wg0 is brought up

Comment: @steeldriver ive tried looking through the whole output and also using grep for numerous strings like wg, wireguard, etc, it isnt present.

Its a VPS, is there the possibility the datacenter could have hidden some output?

Comment: @steeldriver managed to locate wg-quick.target, labelled different to my other machine(wg-quick@wg0.service)

Answer (score 0):

WireGuard is not a service; it is a kernel module. There is no associated userspace process that would represent it, so there's no need for a systemd service.

The only thing you'll find in systemd – *sometimes* – is a service for some or other tool that was used to **configure** WireGuard, such as `wg-quick@something.service`, but that's 100% optional. The WireGuard interfaces might have been created as part of another service, such as `systemd-networkd` or `NetworkManager` or even `ifup@wg0`, and they might even have been created entirely "by hand" using `ip link add` + `wg set` (which is indeed how wg-quick does it).